# How to access local IP with Public IP

Tags: networking, router, port-forwarding

I was accessing my router remotely with port 80 and my local server with port 8080 but I did mistake and configured my local server with port 80. Now I am unable to change local server port remotely and don't know how to access router. When I enter public IP it goes through local server not router. Is it possible to access my router with public IP now?

Example: 192.168.1.1 is router and 192.168.1.20 is local server and both of them have 80 port.

When I access public IP it open the xx.20 IP not the router.

I can't access any of them physically.

Comment: Please tell us which router do you use and how is the address and port translation configured on the router. Do you use any automatic configuration of the address translation? (UPnP / NAT-PMP / PCP) If you have no idea, which web server on which OS do you run?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your router can forward each port to one machine as a time. This means that you have overwritten the external 80 to your local server.

I'm afraid that the firewall will only allow local machine make changes now, you have to go to you location.

On the other hand if you have remote screen access(VNC, RDP, X) to one of the computers you can access router from it, because its same thing to the router as local access anyway.

Also as you might already know its very unsafe to allow remote administration to you router, unless you have a very good password and user, which would still make me nervous.